# Assigning URL as a value in Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I try to assigne a value to a variable in heroku.
*heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production* -> works fine.

But this does't work ->
heroku config:set DATABASE='mongodb+srv://Admin:@cluster0-vxluw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"&"w=majority'

I'm following a tutorial and in the tutorial it works with ' '.
I tried using " ", '', $() to wrap the string. Nothing works.

I get weird error:
The system can not find the stated file.
The command "**w**" is either misspelled or could not be found.

It seems that the ending of the link (&**w**=majority) causes the problem. That would explain the "w" in the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku config:set DATABASE="mongodb+srv://Admin:@cluster0-vxluw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue while trying to assign the MONGODB_URL to Heroku.
However removing the '&w=majority' at the end gave no errors and still worked.
The **w=majority** is for write concern, as described in the MongoDB docs. You can read more about it on [MongoDB DOCS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#write-concern)